# Populating a ListView from an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-listview

I have started an Activity with an Intent that should contain a List, however when I gather the data and bind it to my ListView the app crashes. I get the error on this line:

```
resultMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, selected));
```

This is my entire Activity. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Result extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> menuList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> selected = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("menuList"); 

        // Configure the listview
        ListView resultMenu = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.menuResult);
        resultMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, selected));
    }
}
```

Comment: add logcat if crashes...

Comment: It says that this line that causes the crash! But it looks perfectly fine to me.. Any ideas?? =====> resultMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, selected));

Comment: In the log cat it goes like this... 06-06 14:58:14.302: E/AndroidRuntime(441):  at com.msyd.MenuProject.Result.onCreate(Result.java:27)

Comment: Add more of the logcat please. There isn't enough information here to tell what's wrong.

Comment: One possible reason might be that the variable `selected` is null. If you are getting a NullPointerException that might be why. If that is the case, check that `ArrayList<String> selected = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("menuList"); ` is actually returning a non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

Since your force close is caused by this line:

```
resultMenu.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, selected));
```

The only two possible errors that I can see are:

1. `selected` is null, or
2. `resultMenu` is null

Both of these cause a Null Pointer Exception. If your file result.xml has a ListView element with `android:id="@+id/resultMenu` then the error is in `selected`.

I am betting that `selected` is possibly a String[] or the Intent does not have a 'menuList' key.

How do you build the Intent used to start your Activity `Result`?